# Ember.js: removing event handler in `willDestroyElement` doesn't happen in time

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-testing

So I have jquery event handler attached to `window`, I'm removing it in `willDestroyElement` hook, but calling the event right after it in test triggers callback anyway (adding some delay in test fixes stuff, but it doesn't seem right...)

```
  _detachHandlers: Ember.on('willDestroyElement', function() {
    $(window).off('resize');    
  })
```

test:

```
  this.render(hbs`
    {{#if show}}
      {{#my-component timesCalled=(mut timesCalled)}}
        <button class='button'>Click me!</button>
      {{/my-component}}
    {{/if}}
  `);
  assert.ok(this.$('button.button').length, 'renders button');
  run(() => $(window).trigger('resize'));
  assert.equal(this.get('timesCalled'), 1, "callback worked one time");

  run(() => this.set('show', false));
  assert.notOk(this.$('button.button').length, 'component disappears');
  run(() => $(window).trigger('resize'));    
  assert.equal(this.get('timesCalled'), 1, "callback detached and counter doesn't change");
```

I guess I need to wrap something in run, but what? Tried many approaches that seemed meaningful but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.on` use the `willDestroyElement` method directly to detach your listeners:

```
willDestroyElement() {
  Ember.$('window').off('resize');
  return this._super(...arguments);
}
```

Comment: Didn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that `willDestroyElement` fires after component's object is getting destroyed (or entering in destroying state), so if my event handler does something with the state of component, the solution might be to check  `isDestroying` and `isDestroyed` flags as well.